# Parse something to jQuery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to jQuery/JavaScript, so please forgive me me things don't make sense.

I have the below function written.

```
$.fn.getFeed = function(feedXML) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: feedXML,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                $(this).html('<li><a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#feed-1');
            });
        }
    });
};
```

But I want to be able to call/use this function tie to specific IDs, say for instance

```
$('#feed-1').getFeed('foo.xml');
$('#feed-2').getFeed('bar.xml');
```

And then in my HTML I have something like this.

```
<ol id="feed-1"></ol>
<ol id="feed-2"></li>
```

Right now, everything is appeneded to just 'feed-1', I'm not sure how I could get it to append to the another ID. How do I make it so it's possible to parse the ID as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the function, `this` refers to the selected elements. So you have to store a reference to them:

```
var target = this;
```

and then pass it to `appendTo`:

```
$(this).html(...).appendTo(target);
```

Example:

```
$.fn.getFeed = function(feedXML) {
    var target = this;     
    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                // ...
                $('<li><a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a></li>').appendTo(target);
                // or target.append('<li><a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a></li>');
            });
        }
    });  
    return this;
};
```

*Edit:* `$(this).html(...)` will not work. It would set the content of the `item` element to what you pass to `html()`. At least in Chrome this throws an error. I think you just want to  create a new list item including the link and the title and append to the list.

For more information about writing jQuery plugins, I suggest to read [*jQuery - Plugins/Authoring*](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) ([especially this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Context))

---

Side note: You should also `return this;` in your function to support method chaining.

Comment: Almost there, but instead of outputting HTML, it's spitting out the entire 'item' contents. Any ideas why this is happening?
Here's the example:
http://goo.gl/xWNiP

Comment: @restatic: It doesn't work at all for me (nothing is displayed). I think what you actually want is this: `$('<li><a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a></li>').appendTo(target)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.getFeed = function(feedXML) {

    var $feedElm = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: feedXML,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                $(this).html('<li><a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo($feedElm);
            });
        }
    });
};
```